# How can I improve our current deployment workflow (with Capistrano)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Our team works on a high-traffic site where we use Capistrano to deploy our Rails apps running on Ubuntu/Apache/Passenger.  We have load balancing setup, so our current procedure to minimize downtime and avoid having customers see Rails' 500 page is as follows (assuming only 2 production servers, just for this example):

- Turn Apache off on production_1  (Load balancing now send all requests to production_2)
- Deploy to 1st server: cap production_1 deploy (turns Apache on at the end of deploy)
- Do some basic tests to ensure nothing went funky
- If something went wrong, turn Apache off and rollback

Then, I follow that procedure for the production_2 server.

As you can see, this is painful, so I'm looking for a better way.  Not to mention the fact that we have more servers and will be adding even more soon.

What alternatives are available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can have different environments called "production_0", "production_1" and use capistrano-ext to provide multistage deployment. the run them as following:

1. cap production_0 deploy
2. cap production_1 deploy

please take a look at [Github pages](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension) howto setup multistage deployment

Comment: Hi mikhailov - Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm familiar with cap multistage and we're already using it.  The problem with that approach is that we want to ensure that our load balancer points to the non-deployment machine first (there have been times when a customer gets forwarded to a Passenger error/500 page during deployments).  If a deployment goes wrong, we want to rollback, but without the load balancer ever forwarding the customer to a fouled up machine.  Also, we've run into issues where 1 machine has a bug and we need to be sure exactly which machine we're looking at while testing.

Comment: disable "deploy:web:enable" trigger automatically and try the following: 1) cap production_0 deploy; (leave 503 response after deploy) and check the deployment 2) cap production_0 deploy:web:enable. do the same with the second instance

Comment: That's a great idea!  Thanks.  We also have several other servers that are used for development and testing, so I don't want to disable "deploy:web:enable" for them.  Maybe there is a way to create a special deployment task (e.g., cap deploy_prod0) which would do exactly what you suggested...?

Comment: feel free to add new environments by do only 2 things: add new file into config/environments/testing.rb and config/deploy/testing.rb. then you can manipulate the callbacks like you want. leave disabled for production, enable - for testing (because there is no load balancer)